# Is AEM authentication Stateless

Tags: authentication, aem, stateless, publisher

Is AEM Authentication (closed user group) stateless ? What happens if we have multiple publisher, will the authentication handler ensure the user is authenticated in all the instance of the publisher ?

Could not find a document confirming this, So any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default AEM Authentication (CRX Login Module) is not stateless , the authentication is confirmed by a login token. When a user logs in the token information is stored under **.tokens** node of the corresponding user node (/home/users). The value of the token is also stored in the browser as a cookie **login-token**. Whenever a request comes in , the cookie value and the token in the repository is compared.[
You can test by deleting the .tokens node and refreshing some page that cannot be accessed by anonymous 
]

In a multi publisher environment the token is created only on the instance which logged the user in. Since other instances cannot find the token for the cookie value in their repositories the request will be rejected.

If you enable sticky sessions , all requests by a particular client are always directed to the same instance.

Here's a page on [Oak's token module](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/security/authentication/tokenmanagement.html) . AEM uses crx token module but how they work is essentially same. Since your credentials are passed to a single instance by a [form based authentication handler](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/authentication/authentication-authenticationhandler/form-based-authenticationhandler.html) the token is created only in one instance. The authentication handler page also has some details on the token and the cookie.

> **UPDATE**:
>   With AEM 6.1 , the authentication can now be made stateless as long as the user exists on all the publish instances. This is done by using a encrypted cookie that can be decrypted by all publish instances when they share the same HMAC key. More information can be found here : https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/security/encapsulated-token.html

Comment: Thanks Sharath for explaining the behaviour. Can you pls share the doc, which explains the same. Also is there a alternative option without using sticky connection. Using sticky connection would impact the dispatchers ability to load balance the requests

Comment: @Raghav , unfortunately all this is not described in a single document to link to. You can go with sticky sessions or figure out a way to copy the nodes under .tokens  to all other instances. As long as the token exists the instance will consider the user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

i think it´s possible if you activate the clustering on your authors, the .token node will be replicated to all instances and while comparing the users token ressource and the cookie the identification succeeds, this is one of the benefits of the jcr philosophy :all is content

Answer (score 0):

Enable encapsulated token option in OSGI. Then it will authenticate seamlessly. But there are 2 prerequisite or conditions to get it worked. One is to put the same HMAC key on all the instances and secondly the user should exist. if these 2 conditions are met then if you login on one stack and the second stack wont required authentication again.